# Spark : Index of a value in Array inside ColumnType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark there using Scala I have a dataset with a column having array like

```
[foo, bar, baz, bei]
[foo, bar, baz, bei]
[foo, zie]
```

Now I want to add another column with Index of a value "bar"

```
[foo, bar, baz, bei]     2  
[foo, zie]  0
```

is there something similar to

```
.withColumn("idx", array_contains(col("Name"),"bar"))
```

which is returning me true/false (I need index of the value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UDF:

```
val df = List(
  Seq("foo", "bar", "baz", "bei"),
  Seq("foo", "bar", "baz", "bei"),
  Seq("foo", "zie")
).toDF()

val getIndex = (seq: Seq[String]) => seq.indexOf("bar") + 1
val getIndexUDF = udf(getIndex)

val result = df.withColumn("idx", getIndexUDF($"value"))
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---+
|value               |idx|
+--------------------+---+
|[foo, bar, baz, bei]|2  |
|[foo, bar, baz, bei]|2  |
|[foo, zie]          |0  |
+--------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2.4.0 Spark provides `array_position` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_position

df.withColumn("idx", array_position($"Name", "bar"))
```